# Dynamically switching device orientation with single ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

I'm currently developing an app that has a single ViewController with a WKWebView object that acts as a client for a web app. It uses JavaScript communication and injection to allow for objects in native Swift to interact with the WebView.

#### My Objective

I have a function, `urlDidChange(_ url: String)`, that fires whenever the WKWebView's raw URL value changes. I'm trying to dynamically set the orientation restrictions, depending on the value of said new `url`, and force-rotate the device to adapt those restrictions once a condition is met.

I'm not sure if this extra information is important, but thought that I'd include it anyway: The UIViewController is also embedded in a UINavigationController. The native NavBar really helps the client feel more like a native app. I haven't setup any custom classes for it and have simply been using `let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar`.

**Desired Example Usage**

```
func urlDidChange(_ url: String) {
    if url.contains("/dashboard") {
        UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
    } else if url.contains("/builder") {
        UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [.portrait, .landscapeRight]
    } else {
        UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .all
    }
    // Set new orientation properties
    // Force device rotation based on newly set properties
    UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()   
}
```

#### Current Code

This is my current setup. I have attempted the following, with no luck:

```
enum Page {
    
    var orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        switch self {
        case .login:        return getDeviceOrientation()
        case .dashboard:    return getDeviceOrientation()
        case .newProject:   return getDeviceOrientation()
        case .builder:      return getDeviceOrientation()
        case .other:        return getDeviceOrientation()
        }
    }
    
    func getDeviceOrientation() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        let phone = Device.isPhone()
        switch self {
        case .login:
            if phone { return .portrait }
            else { return .all }
        case .dashboard:
            if phone { return .portrait }
            else { return .all }
        case .newProject:
            if phone { return .portrait }
            else { return .all }
        case .builder:
            if phone { return [.portrait, .landscapeRight] }
            else { return .all }
        case .other:
            if phone { return .portrait }
            else { return .all }
        }
    }
```

**ViewController**

Finally, to apply the new orientation properties, I use this:

```
func urlDidChange(_ url: String) {
    let page = Page.get(forURL: url)    // Returns Page case for current URL
    
    UIDevice.current.setValue(page.orientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation() 
}
```

### Bonus question

Is there a more efficient way of using enumerations to combine the Device properties with my Page enum (ie. `case .builder` with different return values for when `Device.isPhone` or when `Device.isPad`)?

As you can see in the code above, I'm simply using if statements to determine which output to provide right now:

```
case .builder:
    if phone { return [.portrait, .landscapeRight] }
    else { return .all }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ViewController is inside a UINavigationController, that might be the reason. Can you try using a custom UINavigationController, that retrieves the orientation from your ViewController? Something like this:

```
struct OrientationConfig {
    let phone: UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    let pad: UIInterfaceOrientationMask

    static let defaultConfig = OrientationConfig(phone: .portrait, pad: .all)
}

enum Page {
    case login
    case dashboard
    case newProject
    case builder
    case other

    static let orientationConfigs: [Page:OrientationConfig] = [
        .login: OrientationConfig.defaultConfig,
        .dashboard: OrientationConfig.defaultConfig,
        .newProject: OrientationConfig.defaultConfig,
        .builder: OrientationConfig(phone: [.portrait, .landscapeRight],
                                    pad: .all),
        .other: OrientationConfig.defaultConfig
    ]
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var page: Page = .login

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let config = Page.orientationConfigs[page] {
            return Device.isPhone ? config.phone : config.pad
        }
        return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }

}

class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let viewController = topViewController as? MyViewController {
            return viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
        }
        return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
}
```